# React Router v6 shows blank Webpage when trying to link webpages together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blogs

I am trying to follow lamadevs Basic blog tutorial for the UI in React on youtube. In the last section of the video I am unable to link my webpages together in App.js because he uses version 5 instead of 6. I tried switching the switch to route instead but it also didnt work. Do I have to download the old react router dom v5 for it to work? Right now it results in a blank Webpage.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kXC2.png)

Comment: Black page means you have an error. Open the browser console and exit type question with the error you see. Also, please do not include images of your coffee. Copy-paste it into a code block in your question. Please also ensure you provide the [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it should be like this:

> ```
> <>
>   <TopBar /> 
>     <BrowserRouter>
>     <Routes>
>       <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
>       </Route>
>     </Routes>
>   </BrowserRouter>,
> </>
> ```

The difference is, now you don't write a component, but element and element is a JSX, and not component function itself.  Try this, it should work.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to link my webpages together making this change

Comment: You are welcome, if this solved your issue, please hit arrow up, so other developers can see it too, that it helped.